# Flip Weights. How to change bias?

Tags: conv-neural-network, cross-correlation, convolution

I am reading serialized weights and put them into a tensorflow network:

```
tf.tanh(tf.nn.conv2d(t_im0, weights, strides=strides0, 'SAME') + bias)
```

If I flip the weights (see Cross Correlation vs Convolution).

From Convolution:
$\begin{bmatrix}
w0 & w1  & b0\\ 
w2 & w3 &  b1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x0 \\ 
x1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

To  Cross Correlation:
$\begin{bmatrix}
b1 &w3 & w2  \\ 
b0 &w1 & w0  
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x0 \\ 
x1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Is this the correct order of the shape for cross correlation?

---

I think that, if I do not want to change the input, I must swap axes:

To  Cross Correlation:
$\begin{bmatrix}
w3 & w2 & b1 \\ 
w1 & w0 & b0 
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x0 \\ 
x1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get the answer to the above query? If not, I think that since you are serializing the weights to put into a network, you do not need to flip 180, for convolution.

In my opinion, you just need to use \begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
w0 & w1  & b0\\ 
w2 & w3 &  b1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x0 \\ 
x1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Tensorflow and other frameworks do not flip their kernels 180, and this is called cross-correlation (just to make it clear), but use the term convolution when doing computations (loosely speaking, which is technically incorrect). A great answer to the above difference @ [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66838/90473)